# Linq macro substitution

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I can build up a sql string by concatenating  a string i.e.

```
String fieldname =”Company”;

String tableName= “Address”;

 “select  “+fieldname+” from “+tableName
```

How can I do this with Linq?

TIA

Stuart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scott Gu talks about [Dynamic linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) here